# NSNumberFormatter does not format correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I am working on a simple app that requires `NSNumberFormatter`. I am trying to get a number rounded off to 2 decimal places with the following code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
formatter.formatterBehavior = NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault;
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = NO;

formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter numberFromString:@"123.12345"]);
```

However, the log output comes out as:

```
123.12345
```

I am totally stumped as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSNumber *num = [formatter numberFromString:@"123.12345"];
NSLog(@"num: %@", num);
```

That created an `NSNumber` from the string value. `NSNumber` does not have any formatting, just the value. The `NSNumber` could have been created in any number of different ways such as `@123.12345`.

Now create an `NSString` with the desired formatting from the `NSNumber`:

```
NSString *strNum = [formatter stringFromNumber:@123.12345];
NSLog(@"strNum: %@", strNum);
```

NSLog output:

> num: 123.12345
>   strNum: 123.12

Comment: Thank you! That worked. However, lets say if I wanted to format a number but have it stay a number, is it recommended that I do `myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:[formatter stringFromNumber:myNumber]];`?

Comment: `NSNumbers` have no display format, they are just floating point or integer numeric values-we don't even know how they are saved internally. Each time you want to display a `NSNu,her` use a `NSNumberFormatter` if you need more formatting that `stringWithFormat:` provides.